# Bootstrap mock-up not displaying at full viewport on iPhone 5s, despite setting it to scale=1

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, viewport

My test site, [test.crownshots.com](http://test.crownshots.com) doesn't seem to be displaying properly on small devices such as the iPhone 5s. iPhone 6 and up works perfectly.

The site seems to be scaled at about 90% so there's a horrible right-hand border. However, I can't tell what's causing it - I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the header but it doesn't seem to affect the final output on small screens.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I tested on Chrome browser, your site did not minimize than 668px.

My solution:

`content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9"`